# ¿Cómo mover un JTextField con Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

En realidad se que un JButton, JLabel o un JTextField se pueden mover con:

```
   .setBounds(x, y, ancho, largo)
```

pero con el código que tengo éstos no se mueven.

```
   public Interfaz(){   //Constructor

   JFrame ventana = new JFrame("Ventana");
  //  ventana.setLayout(new BorderLayout(60, 20));

    pan3 = new JPanel();

   // ventana.setLayout(null);
    ventana.add(pan3, BorderLayout.EAST);

    LDado = new JTextField();
    FIN = new JButton();

     agregarPanel_3();

    ventana.setSize(850, 700);
    ventana.setLocation(230, 55);
    ventana.setVisible(true);
    ventana.setResizable(false);
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                                                          
}//Fin de constructor

private void agregarPanel_3() {

   LDado.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 60));

   pan3.add(LDado);



  FIN.setBounds(25, 25, 120, 500);
  pan3.add(FIN);

//    pan3.add(FIN);
  //  FIN.setVisible(true);
    }}
```

Con el

```
 .setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 60));
```

sí le doy el tamaño a la cajita pero no puedo moverlo en (x, y). Tengo la ligera sospecha que se trata sobre algun Layout que uso mal o no debo usar.
Estoy comenzando con esto de Java swing agradecería mucho una respuesta.

Comment: Debes asignar un `layout null` al `Jpanel` para poder usar `setBounds` pan3.setLayout(null), realiza esto antes de cualquier `add`, si quieres mover el componente durante la ejecución de la aplicación tendrás que repintar tu ventana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo puedes usar `Component#setBounds` con containers que **no tengan un layout**, es decir, un layout null: `panel3.setLayout(null);`. Por defecto, un JPanel es inicializado con `FlowLayout`.

Comment: Ahora lo veo. Y cómo muevo éstos botones o etiquetas dentro de un panel que coloco por ejemplo a la izquierda de la ventana y otro panel a la derecha.

Comment: En la respuesta dice que solo debes asignar `null` como layout al panel y podrás ubicar los elementos como te plazca.